# Эмуляция нажатия мыши с определенными координатами

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть объект Obj с переопределенным событием нажатия кнопки мыши.

```
private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  double X = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement).X;
}
```

Как программно сэмулировать нажатие мыши в определенных координатах?

Делаю так:

```
MouseDevice mouseDev = InputManager.Current.PrimaryMouseDevice;
MouseButtonEventArgs mouseEvent = new MouseButtonEventArgs(mouseDev,0,MouseButton.Left);
//Как прописать конкретные координаты?
OnMouseDown(Obj,mouseEvent);
```

Comment: Если речь о кликере, то вас спасёт Win32 API P/Invoke метод `SendInput`. Штука не простая, но только пока в первый раз разбираетесь.

Comment: Или если не зочется заморачиваться, есть NuGet пакет [InputSimulator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulator)